# bazel rules_foreign_cc cmake_external - Unable to locate static library

Tags: c++, bazel

I have used configure_make and other features of rules_foreign_cc for quite some time. This is a fantastic project. I have run into a [simple but old C++ project](https://github.com/devguy-com/MD5) that is giving me trouble. I suspect it's caused by the use of configure_in_place but that is just a wild guess. I spent a few hours tracing through the code but couldn't figure out a fix.

I am running bazel 3.2.0 on OSX High Sierra with the rules_foreign_cc master branch that has [#403](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/pull/403) merged. This PR enables running autoreconf via configure_make.

I could of course work around this issue by making a real Bazel project for this simple project. I am submitting this issue in the hopes that fixing a bug or correcting my user error will be an easy task for a rules_foreign_cc expert.

### WORKSPACE

```
workspace(name = "foo")

http_archive(
    name = "rules_foreign_cc",
    strip_prefix = "rules_foreign_cc-master",
    url = "https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_foreign_cc/archive/master.zip",
)

load("@rules_foreign_cc//:workspace_definitions.bzl", "rules_foreign_cc_dependencies")

rules_foreign_cc_dependencies()

all_content = """filegroup(name = "all", srcs = glob(["**"]), visibility = ["//visibility:public"])"""

http_archive(
    name = "md5",
    build_file_content = all_content,
    strip_prefix = "MD5-master",
    url = "https://github.com/devguy-com/MD5/archive/master.zip"
)
```

### BUILD

```
load("@rules_foreign_cc//tools/build_defs:configure.bzl", "configure_make")

configure_make(
    name = "md5",
    autoreconf = True,
    configure_command = "configure",
    configure_in_place = True,
    lib_source = "@md5//:all",
    make_commands = [
      "make libmd5.a",
    ],
    out_lib_dir = "",
    static_libraries = ["libmd5.a"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

### Run Bazel

```
$ bazel build --sandbox_debug -s --verbose_failures --sandbox_debug md5
```

### Build Output

The complete [build output](https://app.buildbuddy.io/invocation/bf56b3dd-4010-4aeb-a59b-ed098a42f625) is available online thanks to [BuildBuddy](https://buildbuddy.io/).

Pertinent snippets:

1.

```
export BUILD_LOG="bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/md5/logs/Configure.log
```

2.

```
ERROR: /Users/user/smart/mac/pe-compute/2019-11-30/BUILD:4:15: output 
'md5/libmd5.a' was not created
```

```
$ cat bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/md5/logs/Configure.log

/private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a146b90161b9da4530683d7f8b2053fd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/12/execroot/exd_edge_compute/external/local_config_cc/wrapped_clang -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -fstack-protector -fcolor-diagnostics -Wall -Wthread-safety -Wself-assign -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O0 -DDEBUG -std=c++11 -isysroot __BAZEL_XCODE_SDKROOT__ -F__BAZEL_XCODE_SDKROOT__/System/Library/Frameworks -F__BAZEL_XCODE_DEVELOPER_DIR__/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.12 -no-canonical-prefixes -Wno-builtin-macro-redefined -D__DATE__="redacted" -D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted" -D__TIME__="redacted"   -c -o src/md5.o src/md5.cpp
ar cr libmd5.a src/md5.o
ranlib libmd5.a
find: /var/folders/3l/rrlrzd555yl84h_l_nytc4w00000gp/T/tmp.XRqtHHSM/md5: No
such file or directory
```

### Root Cause

The output library libmd5.a is located at 
/var/folders/3l/rrlrzd555yl84h_l_nytc4w00000gp/T/tmp.XRqtHHSM.

However, configure_make is looking in that directory's md5 subdirectory.

Using out_lib_dir=".." does not solve the problem. out_lib_dir must be set to an empty string because this particular project creates the library in the project's root directory.

```
$ ls -l /var/folders/3l/rrlrzd555yl84h_l_nytc4w00000gp/T/tmp.XRqtHHSM
```

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff     139 Jun 10 06:36 BUILD.bazel -> /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a146b90161b9da4530683d7f8b2053fd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1/execroot/exd_edge_compute/external/md5/BUILD.bazel
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff     135 Jun 10 06:36 LICENSE -> /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a146b90161b9da4530683d7f8b2053fd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1/execroot/exd_edge_compute/external/md5/LICENSE
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff    2573 Jun 10 06:36 Makefile
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff     139 Jun 10 06:36 Makefile.in -> /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a146b90161b9da4530683d7f8b2053fd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1/execroot/exd_edge_compute/external/md5/Makefile.in
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff     134 Jun 10 06:36 README -> /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a146b90161b9da4530683d7f8b2053fd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1/execroot/exd_edge_compute/external/md5/README
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff     137 Jun 10 06:36 WORKSPACE -> /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a146b90161b9da4530683d7f8b2053fd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1/execroot/exd_edge_compute/external/md5/WORKSPACE
drwxr-xr-x  7 user  staff     224 Jun 10 06:36 autom4te.cache
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff      96 Jun 10 06:36 config
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   23872 Jun 10 06:36 config.log
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff   32037 Jun 10 06:36 config.status
-rwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff  142714 Jun 10 06:36 configure
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff     140 Jun 10 06:36 configure.ac -> /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a146b90161b9da4530683d7f8b2053fd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1/execroot/exd_edge_compute/external/md5/configure.ac
-rw-r--r--  1 user  staff   12560 Jun 10 06:36 libmd5.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 user  staff     139 Jun 10 06:36 rfc1321.txt -> /private/var/tmp/_bazel_user/a146b90161b9da4530683d7f8b2053fd/sandbox/darwin-sandbox/1/execroot/exd_edge_compute/external/md5/rfc1321.txt
drwxr-xr-x  8 user  staff     256 Jun 10 06:36 src
drwxr-xr-x  3 user  staff      96 Jun 10 06:36 tests
```